# import existing Go project into eclipse

Tags: eclipse, go, goclipse

I've installed and configured GOClipse v0.16.1 on eclipse Neon (obviously, I've installed GO and tested it from command line).

To test the plugin, I created a GO project with a command and a package, formatted, built and ran the command. All good!

But when I try to import an existing GO project, eclipse doesn't recognise it as a GO project. Hence, I can't build it from within eclipse. The source is located in $GOPATH/src where the test project's code is.

Is there anything else I need to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "Import existing projects into workspace" wizard only works for existing **Eclipse** projects, that is, locations that have Eclipse's `.project` file already.

If you have just a Go project, you should use the Eclipse "New Go Project" wizard, and specify on the wizard the location of your existing Go project.

Comment: Cool. Thanks mate. I didn't think I can use "new project" wizard to import an "existing" project.

Comment: Use can use the "new project" wizard @Amir, see this link: https://github.com/GoClipse/goclipse/blob/latest/documentation/UserGuide.md#project-creation